# Rails 4 + Devise + Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm attempting to install Devise on a rather simple event creating/displaying Rails 4 app. I have 2 static pages and the index page displaying without authentication, and all is well there. Anything else kicks you to the "sign up" page. From there, when I attempt to create an account for myself (to simply see the other pages- simple vanilla devise installation attempt) I get a "No route matches [POST] "/registrations/user" error when clicking "submit" (f.submit)

I am using Rails 4, have the 3.0.3 version of Devise, bundled it, ran "rails generate devise:install" to install it, ran "rails generate devise user", ran db:migrate, raked the routes, and restarted the Rails server.

I even recreated the button action with the "correct" route and "get post" - no dice.

Anybody have any idea? I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's always tricking debugging sever-side code without seeing it in action, but here's what should work.

yourappname/config/routes.rb :

```
devise_scope :user do
    # matches the url '/register' to the registration controller's 'new' action and creates a :register symbol inorder to reference the link dynamically in the rest of the code
    get 'register', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register
end
```

(Assuming your register button is in your app's partial)

yourappname/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "Register", register_path, class: "btn" %>
```

Now you could actually put that link_to anywhere, in any page, and it'll work. The reason for this is the 'register_path'.

When you create your route, the `as: :register` parameter creates a global variable that can be accessed throughout your app.

the `register_path` variable in your `link_to` method will always call the right action, even if you change your routes file.

It's just syntax. You could create any symbol you want. This would also work:

routes.rb:

```
# Inside get method, third parameter
as: :bowtiesarecool
```

someview.html.erb:

```
# Inside link_to method, second parameter
bowtiesarecool_path
```

Just match the variable name with the symbol name and a put a _path after it. The link_to method will handle everything else!

Comment: Turns out that I have a Registration model that conflicts with Devise's Registration stuff. What a nightmare. No idea how Im going to fix this.

Comment: Precisely why I don't like using gems too much!

But why not let Devise handle all of the registration?

Failing that (I don't know anything about your application after all!), why not get really familiar with the signup process:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

and find out what devise is doing under the hood.